# C - Segmentation Fault Somewhere

Tags: c

I keep getting a Segmentation fault. I figured out that it happens between these two lines:

```
            printf("%s - File exists!\n", file_name);
            printf("inforloop");
```

But I'm unsure why the segmentation fault keeps occuring.
This is the entire code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>

FILE *fp;
char err_message[128], file_name[128];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc <= 2)
    {
        printf("ERROR : Usage %s <file name>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    int i = 1;
    for(i; i< argc; i++)
    {
        strcpy(file_name, argv[i]);
        if ((access(file_name, F_OK)) != -1)
        {
            printf("begining of for loop\n");
            printf("%s - File exists!\n", file_name);
            printf("inforloop");
            fclose(fp);
        }
        else
       {
           sprintf(err_message, "open %s", file_name);
           perror(err_message);
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Outcome:

```
 1
 begining of for loop
 date.txt - File exists!
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: You didn't assign `fp`.

Comment: Looks like C. C++ is a different language. Do not add unrelated tags.

Comment: A debugger would tell you exactly where the fault occurred, and would be quicker (in the long run) then using SO as a debugging service - even if you are stuck with raw GDB.

Answer (score 4):

You're `fclose`ing `fp`, which you have never `fopen`ed, or even initialized.

The output is cut off before printing `inforloop` because your standard output is line-buffered, and there is no line feed after `inforloop`.